# What's the difference between dotnet_diagnostics and equivalent rules under dotnet_style_, csharp_ etc.?

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, editorconfig

For example, in `.editorconfig` I can require fields to be readonly using both:

```
# IDE0044: Make field readonly
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0044.severity = warning
```

and

```
dotnet_style_readonly_field = true:warning
```

Both will show up in the editor, both will cause the issue to be fixed upon running `dotnet format`. What are the differences between both options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is not aware of the `option = value:severity` syntax, e.g:

```
dotnet_style_readonly_field = true:warning
```

So if you use that, the build will produce warnings/errors only for IDE live analysis. But if you want to enforce code-style on build, you need to use the `dotnet_diagnostic.RuleId.severity = severity` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

[The previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71350682/4553982) is not completely correct, because it is missing `EnforceCodeStyleInBuild = true` setup outside `.editorconfig`, but *the answer* has much more complexity, see [this](https://developers.mews.com/c-code-style-by-editorconfig-in-net-5-sdk-and-beyond/) article.

In practice, you have to consider what rule you want to enforce, what IDEs and what version of those IDEs you have, if you have CI/CD etc.